# How to configure .htaccess on server using Laravel 4

Tags: php, apache, laravel-4

I have a problem with .htaccess file, I think this is all about it. When I trying to run my website on screen show errors:

> Warning: require(**DIR**/bootstrap/autoload.php) [function.require]:
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /index.php on line
>   21
>
> Warning: require_once(**DIR**/bootstrap/start.php)
>   [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in /index.php on line 35
>
> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening
>   required '**DIR**/bootstrap/start.php'
>   (include_path='.:/:/usr/local/php/pear5') in /index.php on line 35

I found some solution but its not works.
This is my .htaccess file:

```
 # Use PHP 5.3
 AddHandler application/x-httpd-php53 .php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
      Options -MultiViews
  </IfModule>
  RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L] </IfModule>
```

The version of php on my server is 5.3

Please help.

Comment: I assume your index page is inside public folder. How your url looks like?

Comment: When I ran my app on localhost url looks like http://localhost:8080, I would like to do something similar on my server to avoid public in url. Url for server looks like website_name.biz, and that's all

Comment: Ok, If your entire laravel framework is inside a folder guess `webapp` in `htdocs` And `index.php` is inside `public` folder i.e. `htdocs/webapp/public/index.php`, Try `localhost:8080/webapp/public/`.

Comment: Doesnt work...
This is my folder structure:
appFolder
 -app
 -bootstrap
 -css
 -images
 -libs
 - .htaccess
 - index.php
 ...
This structure works for localhost but on server the errors occured.
My laravel folder is in vendor/laravel

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work. In your *index.php* file configure

```
require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/start.php';
```

instead of

```
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/start.php';
```

and in `bootstrap/paths.php` change

```
'public' => __DIR__.'/../public',
```

to

```
'public' => __DIR__.'/../',
```

Comment: Now i have:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php on line 411.
Update php version to 5.3 solved first problem, but now occured another.

Comment: Check the indicated `helpers.php` page. Laravel installation says it needs PHP>=5.4. http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/installation#server-requirements

Comment: This peace of code solved the problem in htaccess.
:Location /*.(php|php4|php5)
Use php5
:Location

But now main view is displayed but the routes doesnt work...When I clicked on some link I have 404 error, page not found.

Comment: Great, You've solved it. You can post it as answer or if my answer also helped, you can edit my answer with your solution. For other problems, it would be good if you provide some codes.